# Mockito: polling wait on verify

Tags: java, mockito

```
@Mock WorkItem;

@Test(timeOut = 300000)
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    <do some testing>

    verifyWorkDone()
}

public void verifyWorkDone() {
    ArgumentCaptor<WorkItemQuery> captor = 
    ArgumentCaptor.forClass(WorkItemQuery.class);
    verify(WorkItem, atLeastOnce()).call(captor.capture());
}
```

I want to change the above code block for `verifyWorkDone()` so that it keeps on retrying to verify until the test times out.

is there a good way to accomplish this? just throw a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing asynchronous behavior usually should not involve polling to check that something has happened as part of test behavior. I suggest isolating the component that will run asynchronously and testing it separately, "normally". Then, test the component that will *wait* on the asynchronous component by mocking the asynchronous component to `wait` a fixed amount of time before responding. You can use this to test the waiting component in all the relevant cases: response comes as expected, response comes but it's an error, response never comes before timeout, etc.

E.g.

```
public interface AsyncObject {
    public void invoke();
    public Object check();
}

public class MyMockAsyncObject implements AsyncObject {

    private long delay;
    private long startTimeMillis;

    public MyMockAsyncObject(long delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public void invoke() {
        startTimeMillis = now();
    }

    public Object check() {
        if (now() - startTimeMillis > delay) {
            return new Object();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class Waiter {

    public AsyncObject myAsyncObject;

    public Waiter(AsyncObject async) {
        this.myAsyncObject = async;
    }

    public Object getResult() {
        myAsyncObject.invoke();
        return this.waitForResult();
    }

    private Object waitForResult() {
        while(// is not timed out) {
            // wait a while
            myAsyncObject.check(); 
            // return result if it's there
        }
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: so what simulates the wait in the testcase of the waiting component? just a sleep? what if the test is flaky or the machine that runs on the test is loaded so it takes longer than the anticipated wait time?

Comment: You would pass the waiting component a mock of the async component. This mock can contain logic to wait a fixed amount before making a response available. In terms of flakiness, the time-honored strategy is to make the time that the mock waits significantly less than the time-out on the waiting component for the "success" test and significantly more for the "failure" test. In the world of today's processors, a couple second difference is quite sufficient. In any case, the behavior of the mock will be much less flaky than the behavior of a true async component.

Comment: I understand the mock containing the wait a fixed amount of time. I am asking what is the testcase (component-in-test) doing while the mock is executing the fixed time of wait? is it like a blocking op on the response?

Comment: It's an actual logical component that waits just like it would in production, it's just that the wait is occurring on a mocked component that is biding its time before returning, not an actual async process. So if your normal wait behavior is "poll every X seconds until timeout" it would do that, and the mock would only return an answer once it's finished waiting. If it's "at the timeout, check if there's an answer", it would do that, and the mock would only return an answer if it had already finished waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Mockito has a feature that solves this problem called [VerificationWithTimeout](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/verification/VerificationWithTimeout.html). I've used this in my code to verify async behavior. Here's what it would look like with a 1000ms timeout:

```
@Mock WorkItem;

@Test
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    <do some testing>
    
    ArgumentCaptor<WorkItemQuery> captor = 
    ArgumentCaptor.forClass(WorkItemQuery.class);
    verify(WorkItem, timeout(1000)
      .atLeastOnce()).call(captor.capture);
}
```